# I can't get my form to submit after using preventdefault

Tags: javascript, html, forms, preventdefault

I have a form inside a modal structure where I recollect some info from the user, after that I want to submit that info into a post request so I can process it in python.

The problem is that I need to check first if the user actually put the info, so I won't get empty values.

I'm using `.preventDefault()` in order to stop the submission and check the values. The program posts fine as long as I don't use the `preventDefault`, and actually doesn't post when using it.
The problem is that after passing all the conditions, it should post, but is not doing it and I don't know why.

Here is the code of the form:

```
<form id="forminout" action="/in_out" method="post">
        <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="incomeModal">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title">Add your new income</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                             <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body" id="new_incomes">
                        <div style="padding:3%">
                            <input step=".01" type="number" class="form-control input-sm" name="incoming" min="0" placeholder="0">
                            <select class="incomselect" name="incomeselects" style="height:30px;">
                                <option selected disabled>This income is coming from?</option>
                                <option value="rent">Rents</option>
                                <option value="salary">Salary</option>
                                <option value="invest_reveneu">Investments reveneus</option>
                                <option value="others">Others</option>
                            </select>
                            <select class="incomdate" name="incomedate" style="height: 30px;">
                                <option selected disabled>Incoming date</option>
                                <option value=5>1 - 5</option>
                                <option value=10>6 - 10</option>
                                <option value=15>11 - 15</option>
                                <option value=20>16 - 20</option>
                                <option value=25>21 - 25</option>
                                <option value=31>26 - 31</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="addinbutt" type="submit">Save changes</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   </form>
```

Which is working fine because the post is actually happening.

And here is the "simplified" code of the post request:

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    $("form").on("submit", function(e){
        errors = 0;
        e.preventDefault();
        if (errors==0)
        {
            document.getElementById("#forminout").submit();
        }
    })
})
```

In this case the `errors==0` condition is only used as a simplification, supposing that all the actual conditions I need to check are ok.

I just can't get it to post.

Comment: Have you tried using `preventDefault` only when an error is found? Right now you are saying, 'do not submit' no matter what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution : write `this.submit()` or `e.target.submit()` instead of `doc.getElById().submit()`

---

```js
$("document").ready(function(){
    $("#forminout").on("submit", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        // ur conditions ...
        this.submit();
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="forminout" action="/in_out" method="post">
        <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="incomeModal">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title">Add your new income</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                             <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body" id="new_incomes">
                        <div style="padding:3%">
                            <input step=".01" type="number" class="form-control input-sm" name="incoming" min="0" placeholder="0">
                            <select class="incomselect" name="incomeselects" style="height:30px;">
                                <option selected disabled>This income is coming from?</option>
                                <option value="rent">Rents</option>
                                <option value="salary">Salary</option>
                                <option value="invest_reveneu">Investments reveneus</option>
                                <option value="others">Others</option>
                            </select>
                            <select class="incomdate" name="incomedate" style="height: 30px;">
                                <option selected disabled>Incoming date</option>
                                <option value=5>1 - 5</option>
                                <option value=10>6 - 10</option>
                                <option value=15>11 - 15</option>
                                <option value=20>16 - 20</option>
                                <option value=25>21 - 25</option>
                                <option value=31>26 - 31</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="addinbutt" type="submit">Save changes</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   </form>
```

## EDIT :

you can even write this based on `e` parameter :

```
$("document").ready(function(){
        $("#forminout").on("submit", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            // ur conditions ...
            e.target.submit();
        })
    })
```